# Why does Jenkins keep sending me to https://127.0.0.1:8080?

Tags: jenkins

I am inexplicably having 50% of my requests to Jenkins redirect me to https://127.0.0.1:8080/. My Jenkins URL is something like http://ci.example.com, which is neither on my localhost or HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured this out after much, much frustration. The issue was only happening when POST'ing data to Jenkins. I used Chrome to record my network traffic and saw a request to http://ci.example.com/j_acegi_security_check, which was returning the `302 Location: https://127.0.0.1:8080/`. Further down I saw that my browser was sending a header for `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` in my request. Ahhh, this is because I had set this up for another website and forgot to deactivate it =(

After deactivating the Header, things have returned to normal.

Hopefully this saves someone else from the headache I suffered.